# Mvc 4 OwinContext Session exipre during execution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, session, ef-code-first

I have developed web site in `mvc 4` which is using **code first entity framework**. I have used HttpContext.GetOwinContext().SignIn while login to my site.

```
 HttpContext.GetOwinContext().SignIn(user, model.RememberMe);
 HttpContext.SetSession(WebConstants.SessionUser, user);
```

When I login it store `user` session. I have one `Index` view. On that View I have create six to seven menu **tabs**. When first time it open it loads first menu tab. When it loads it fetch some data from tables and display on view. So each of tabs some data. I have created one `basecontroller`. In this controller I am accessing the session data.

Here is my `basecontroller`

```
protected Domain.ClientAgg.User GetUserContext()
{
    return HttpContext.GetSession<SN.Domain.ClientAgg.User>(WebConstants.SessionUser);
}
protected string GetUserClientShortname()
{
    return HttpContext.GetSession<SN.Application.DTO.UserContext>(WebConstants.SessionUser).Client.ShortName;
}
protected int GetUserClientId()
{
    return HttpContext.GetSession<SN.Application.DTO.UserContext>(WebConstants.SessionUser).Client.Id;
}

protected SN.Application.DTO.UserContext GetClientUserContext()
{
    return HttpContext.GetSession<SN.Application.DTO.UserContext>(WebConstants.SessionUser);
}
.....
......
......
```

I am using this methods to get data from table and show it on tabs view. Here my issue is if I continuously navigate between these tabs session get's expire. I think this issue occurs if current process is in execution and I click on other tab so at that time execution process breaks. Can anyone tell me how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please, check your expiration settings in Startup configuration, for example:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(4.0),
            SlidingExpiration = true
        });
```

You can read more about expiration on
http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/ASPNET-Identity-Cookie-Authentication-Timeouts/